# Setting up two different static directories in node.js Express framework

Tags: static, node.js, express, duostack

Is it possible? I would like to set up two different directories to serve static files. Let's say /public and /mnt

Comment: [This page](http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/14aaea4245d6d7b7) seems to say that it is possible but doesn't go into much more detail than that.

Answer (score 175):

You can also set the path that static files will be served to the web from by specifying an additional (first) parameter to `use()` like so:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/public2", express.static(__dirname + "/public2"));
```

That way you get two different directories on the web that mirror your local directories, not one url path that fails over between two local directories.

In other words the URL pattern:

```
http://your.server.com/public/*
```

Serves files from the local directory `public` while:

```
http://your.server.com/public2/*
```

Serves files from the local directory `public2`.

BTW this is also useful if you don't want static to serve the files from the root of your server but rather from a more qualified path.

HTH

Comment: Perfect @facetcounter! Just pointed a script to my directory! script(src="/public2/alertTest.js")

Comment: If using React and trying to serve two separate apps, you need to add `"homepage": "/public"` and `"homepage": "/public2"` to the respective react app's package.json. For more info on using two react apps see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569896/4746648

Comment: this is very useful specially when you want a `shared` folder so that you can use `"./"` and `"./shared"` and boom you can easily share js files :3 Thank you

Comment: I want to serve sub directories like, public/js, public/css, public/img, etc. separately so that I can keep maxage different for them rather than keeping same. does that affects performance? Should I serve entire directory /public.

Answer (score 64):

You can also "merge" directories into a single visible directory

**Directory Structure**

- `/static`
- `/alternate_static`

**Code**

```
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/alternate_static"));
```

Both static and alternate_static will be served as if they were in the same directory. Watch out for filename clobbers, though.

Comment: If I understand correctly file name conflicts don't happen because node uses the first version of the file it finds. If it sees `main.js` in `static/` it won't continue to look in `alternate_static/`.

Comment: That's still a clobber if you were expecting the file in `alternate_static` to be ever served.

Comment: I want to serve sub directories like, public/js, public/css, public/img, etc. separately so that I can keep maxage different for them rather than keeping same. does that affects performance? Should I serve entire directory /public.

Answer (score 43):

It's not possible by one middleware injection, but you can inject `static` middleware multiple times:

```
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public1'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public2'));
});
```

**Explanation**

Look at [connect/lib/middleware/static.js#143](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js#L143):

```
path = normalize(join(root, path));
```

There is `options.root` is static root, which you define in `express.static` or `connect.static` call, and `path` is request path.

Look more at [connect/lib/middleware/static.js#154](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js#L154):

```
  fs.stat(path, function(err, stat){
    // ignore ENOENT
    if (err) {
      if (fn) return fn(err);
     return ('ENOENT' == err.code || 'ENAMETOOLONG' == err.code)
       ? next()
       : next(err);
```

Path checked only once, and if file not found request passed to next middleware.

*Update for Connect 2.x*

Links to code are inactual for Connect 2.x, but multiple static middleware usage are still posible as before.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same issue but I managed it to resolve it, after a long search for this quest.

**Step 1:**

Serve the static files in the pathnames of /public and /mnt

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '<path_to_the_folder_you_want_to_serve_public>')));

app.use('/mnt', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '<path_to_the_folder_you_want_to_serve_mnt>')));
```

**Step 2:**

My plan was to deploy two Angular client apps in a single NodeJS server.

So I ran the *'ng build'* on both Angular client apps.

I placed one of dist folder in '/public' folder and another dist folder in '/mnt'.

**Step 3:**

Need to modify the index.html by changing the following things to show the public folder content,

```
<script src="./public/runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="./public/polyfills.js" defer></script>
<script src="./public/styles.js" defer></script>
<script src="./public/vendor.js" defer></script>
<script src="./public/main.js" defer></script>
```

Need to modify the index.html by changing the following things to show the mnt folder content,

```
<script src="./mnt/runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="./mnt/polyfills.js" defer></script>
<script src="./mnt/styles.js" defer></script>
<script src="./mnt/vendor.js" defer></script>
<script src="./mnt/main.js" defer></script>
```

**Important Note :** Change the .js files path based on the static folder serving path.

**Step 4:**

In one path, you can serve public and on another you can serve mnt.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/index.html'));
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../mnt/dist/index.html'));
})
```

Now you are good to go. Run & Test it.

Comment: On step 3 above, you do not need to edit each individual file, you can simply add a homepage field in the package.json file like this: "homepage": "/mnt"

Comment: You will also encounter issues when moving/serving from the public folder to mnt folder as you will need to refresh your browser otherwise the files from new folder wont load. The solution is simple. In  each client folder add a reload function on your preferred reload route: <Route path = '/mnt/*'  render= {(props)=>window.location.reload()} />

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const pagesPath = path.join(__dirname, '/cheatsheet');
const cssPath = path.join(__dirname, '/stylesheet');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();

app.use("/cheatsheet" ,express.static(pagesPath));
app.use("/stylesheet",express.static(cssPath)); 

app.get('/',(request,response)=>{
    response.send('Hello CSS!!!');
  });

app.get('/bad',(request,response)=>{
response.send({error: 'Bad Request'});

});
app.listen(port, ()=> {
console.log(`Server is running on Port ${port}` );
console.log(__dirname);
```

});

```
// folder structure
/cheatsheet/index.html
/stylesheet/style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `express.static` inside custom middleware:

```
app.use(customMiddleware())
```

where

```
const customMiddleware = function() {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        // do some dynamic code
        // or
        return express.static(__dirname + "/public")(req, res, next);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an example of some dynamic code that can go into the middleware here?

Answer (score 0):

we can dynamically enable static files in nodejs server with respect to perticular route

```
app.use("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.isAuth === undefined) {
        let middleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname, "staticPages"));
        middleware(req, res, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use `:dir` instead of `*`

eg

```
this.app.use('/:microsite', express.static(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'client/')))
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense