# CSS not loaded in Node Express application

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have a problem with my Node Express project. I cannot seem to have the CSS load to the browser. Here is my how mu project structure looks like.

Note: The AdminView folder from the views are the admin section page (cms), so it contains its own css, javascripts, and images on the folder.

```
public/
  css/
  images/
  js/
routes/
  index.js
  users.js
views/
  AdminView/
  layouts/
    layout.hbs
  index.hbs
```

When I access the index(.hbs) page, it loads the CSS well. I know this worked because:

- I have specified the layout file on the app.js

  ```
  app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout' , layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts'}));
  ```
- I have specified the css,js, and images on the layout.hbs file

I am trying to access this page from my user.js route.

My question is, how do I load the CSS file on the AdminView folder? When I inspect on the page, it tells me that it is trying to load the CSS from localhost:8000/**users**/css/bootstrap.css.

How do I make it so that this particular route is taking getting the css,js, and images from the folder below?

[image]

EDIT: added some routing files,

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index' , {title: 'Test Title'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**user.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.send('user details');
  res.render('AdminView/index2', {title: 'Admin Page'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can you show your routing codes?

Comment: to serve static files you can use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express

Comment: @Pawan So i noticed that in my app.js uses `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. This worked for the main website, but how do i make another one to direct it to the css on the AdminView folder? I cant seem to do it on the user.js route file.

Comment: @Adam like serving static from public you can also serve them from other location you just need to have the name in place for e.g if u have css folder at parent in AdminView then you can do app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/AdminView')));

Comment: @Pawan thanks for the fast reply. I have tried using the code used from the app.js (the same as you given) to my users.js route. It seems that it still gave me a 404 error, I believe it is still trying to access the CSS from the public folder. So I assume that it ignores the code that you give (that I already wrote) on the users.js route file and only runs the one on the app.js file?

Comment: @Adam can you show your updated app.js and user.js

Comment: @Pawan app.js http://pastebin.com/q6KuBgY6 users.js http://pastebin.com/7pj6Sai0 . Thank you so much for taking your time.

Comment: Hi Adam its a file resolution error, the code app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/AdminView/bootstrap'))) in your user.js trying to access the directory within routes folder only(i.e /routes/view/AdminView/bootstrap) that's why you getting 404, so try to resolve actual path . what you can do here you can put this code app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/AdminView/bootstrap')))  within your app.js only it should work. Refer this link for more info http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: This thread answered my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973432/setting-up-two-different-static-directories-in-node-js-express-framework

@Pawan thanks for your reply, your answers made it clear!