# How do I source files in a separate directory for use in the .html file when serving the .html file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a `node.js` server just for serving a .html file , set up like this:

```
var http=require("http");
var express=require("express");
var path=require("path");

var port=process.env.port||5000;

var app=express();

//Serve ALL resource files statically
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/publicResources"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/private"));


app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/publicResources/webpage.html");
});

console.log("We're up");

app.listen(port);
```

And then in webpage.html I want to use an image, which I'm storing in the private directory:
`<img src="../private/puppy.jpg">`

When I run this with `node`, and view it in chrome, I get the standard error message:
`failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, pertaining to `http://localhost:5000/private/puppy.jpg`.

Why can't the .html file source the image? - I understand that you need to serve the static files with `node.js`, and then use the source path relative to the .html file in which it is written, both of which I am doing (I think). What might be going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up two different static directories in node.js Express framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973432/setting-up-two-different-static-directories-in-node-js-express-framework)

Answer (score 1):

`express.static()` serves its files directly on the server root, without any path prefix.

Therefore, you're actually serving `/puppy.jpg`.

If you want to serve it with `private/` in the URL, you need to mount `express.static()` in that path:

```
app.use("private", express.static(__dirname+"/private"));
```

See the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: Hmmn, I just tried that and got exactly the same error message - do I keep the 'src' attribute the same in the `.html` file?