# Routing inside multiple react clients served by express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, react-router-v4

I am trying to serve multiple react apps through a single server, each one of the apps should have routing within it.
for example: 
app 1 will be accessed by '/' and then '/about' '/pricing' etc.
app 2 will be accessed by '/app2' and then '/app2/register' '/app2/login'

I have followed this question: [Serving multiple react apps with client-side routing in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416277/serving-multiple-react-apps-with-client-side-routing-in-express)

It works fine but the routing within the nested client doesn't seem to work.

here is my code:

server.js:

```
//*** server.js
//**************
// Serve app 2 static files
app.use('/app2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client_app2/build')));
// Serve app 1 static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client_app1/build')));
// Serve app 2 build index
app.get('/customer/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client_customer', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
// Serve app 1 build index
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client_main', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

app 1: (the main one)

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Fragment>
                <h1>App 1 - Main App</h1>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/about'>
                        <h2>About</h2>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/pricing'>
                        <h2>Pricing</h2>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

app 1 package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:80"
```

app2:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Fragment>
                <h1>App 1 (nested app)</h1>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/login'>
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/register'>
                        <h2>Registration</h2>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

app 2 package.json:

```
    "proxy": "http://localhost:80/app2",
    "homepage": "/app2"
```

as I said it all works fine except for the routing inside app 2,
soo going to 'app2/login' will be the same as going to 'app2/'.

maybe I should change my approach here?

I should mention that I am deploying with Heroku and this is the reason I am using port 80
although the code seems to run the same even if I change it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned up to be fairly simple, each route within the nested client app should be provided with a full path like so:

app 2 (the nested app):

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Fragment>
                <Navbar />
                <h1>Customer App (app 2 - nested)</h1>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/app2/login'>
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/app2/register'>
                        <h2>Registration</h2>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

app 2 package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:80/app2",
"homepage": "/app2"
```

I originally thought that the proxy and homepage values would mean that the root address of app2 would be '/app2' but it seems that it stayed '/'.
I am not sure why it is that way and if someone knows and can clarify that, it would be great.