# Trying to serve different react apps with node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

### I am trying to serve different applications (two made with React and one API made with Express.JS)

#### In fact, the API works fine and it works in "/api" route. What I need to do is the following:

- The Frontend app must be in "/" path
- The admin panel must be in "/admin" (or whatever)

#### If I set any React app to serve in "/" it works fine, but if I set the other app in "/subfolder" it doesn't works

This is my server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true }));
app.use(express.json());

//use cors

// Import DB Connection
require("/db/pathConfig");

// Import routes
const apiRoutes = require('routePath');
const usersRoutes = require('routePath');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/FE', {redirect: true}));
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + '/adPanel'));
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads', {redirect: false}))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.resolve('FE/index.html'))
})

/* app.get('/landing/*', (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.resolve('landing/index.html'))
}) */

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Does this help you anyhow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416277/serving-multiple-react-apps-with-client-side-routing-in-express

Comment: when you refer to `http://localhost:{port}/admin` what it returns

Comment: I guess your problem is related to serving in subdirectory. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396427/how-to-bundle-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-on-a-server)

Comment: Try to put the `/admin` route before the `/` route, the order can be important when working with routes in an API.

Comment: @EzizHudayberdiyev blank page

Comment: @BastienGrignon I will try..

Comment: @HectorManuelCabreraVilla create basic index.html with some `<p1>Its admin page<p1>` in static folder (adPanel). And as default it should return contents from index.html