# How to make a virtual static path by express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a virtual static path using express but there was some problem I can't deal with.
That's what I found in doc of Express:

```
// Serve static content for the app from the “public” directory 
// in the application directory:
// GET /style.css etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Mount the middleware at “/static” to serve static content only when 
// their request path is prefixed with “/static”:
// GET /static/style.css etc.
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Here is the directory structures:

```
disk
  static
    css
    js
    img
  index.html
server.js
```

If I just try the code below, nothing go wrong. And I can find the same directory structures in Sources option in Chrome DevTools;

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
```

But when I try to make a virtual directory using code below, it went wrong.

```
app.use('/music', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
```

My site can not show correctly and console show errors of getting static files .That's what i found in Chrome DevTools:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6W5G.png),
[directory structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMWqU.png)

I thought the directory structures should like this "music/static/css".
Can anyone tell me what's wrong. Thx!

Comment: Try this: `var path = require('path'); var STATIC_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'); app.use('/music', express.static(STATIC_PATH);`

Comment: Did you tryed this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973432/setting-up-two-different-static-directories-in-node-js-express-framework