# serving different directories based on device in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

i have build two versions of an angular2 webApp.
 a desktop version and a mobile version.
each version is in a separate directory.
so i am trying to serve the different directories in express.js based on the device that requesting the app, but i cant make it work....

```
app.use(express.static(path.join('../versions'),{index:false}))

app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
  const regEx = /mobile|iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|opera|mini|windows\sce|palm|smartphone|iemobile|ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle/i;
  let isMobile = regEx.test(req.headers['user-agent']);

  if(isMobile){
   return res.sendFile(path.join('/home/anton/dev/myTips/versions/mobileV/dist','/index.html'));
  }else{
    return res.sendFile(path.join('/home/anton/dev/myTips/versions/desktopV/dist/desktopV','/index.html'));
  }
})
```

i get this errors in the browser when i am trying to run the app in mobile mode or desktop mode:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    runtime.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    polyfills.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    styles.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    vendor.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    main.js:1
```

Comment: The links to the scripts are dead and thus lead to 404 HTML documents starting with `<`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230614/5734311

Comment: but i dont understand why they are broken, because if i use just :`app.use(express.static(path.join('__dirName/mobileV, 'index.html)` the app does load up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up two different static directories in node.js Express framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973432/setting-up-two-different-static-directories-in-node-js-express-framework)